# c# Boolean Overriding

Tags: c#, boolean

I am trying to use boolean when overriding. It all works but the boolean one

`public Bike(String colour, int gears, Boolean bell)
                    : base (colour)`

```
Bike B1 = new Bike("red ", 5, No);
        //B1.Name = "Red";
        Console.WriteLine("" + B1.ToString());
        //Console.WriteLine("Name: " + B1.Name);
```

The sentence I am trying to create is 
The red bike has 5 gears and no bell

The "no" bit is the boolean one so how do you use boolean using the word No because when I have it on the program like above "Bike B1 = new Bike("red ", 5, No);" I get an error saying "The name 'No' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: bools can only accept `true` or `false` literals. Did you think `No` was a valid boolean value?

Answer (score 2):

`No` is not a keyword in C#. For bool type, use `true` or `false`

Comment: You're missing a tick towards the beginning of that line, inverting what you meant to do :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that you are not understanding well data type. 
Please to read about the boolean [bool (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8f5xwh7.aspx).
This said: "The **bool** keyword is an alias of System.Boolean. It is used to declare variables to store the Boolean values, **true** and **false**."
If you require a Boolean variable that can also have a value of **null**, use **bool?**.
you  may try something like this

```
public Bike(String colour, int gears, Boolean bell)
                : base (colour){
 ////.......
public override ToString(){
    string yesNo=(bell==true)? "with one":"and no";
    return string.Format("The {0} bike has {1} {2} bell", colour, gears, yesNo);

}
}
```